# Snags when discovering the asymptotic behavior of an integral

Tags: asymptotics, definite-integrals

I have trouble in discovering the asymptotic behavior (i.e, the asymptotic expansion) of the following integral:

$$\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+(n\pi+x)\sin x}\tag1$$

The motivation is about the convergence of such improper integral:

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\beta dx}{1+x^\alpha\abs{\sin x}}\qquad\alpha,\beta>0$$

The preceding integral is due to G.Hardy, which could be solved in such a way:

$$I_n=\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{x^\beta dx}{1+x^\alpha\abs{\sin x}}=\int_0^\pi\frac{(n\pi+x)^\beta dx}{1+(n\pi+x)^\alpha\sin x}$$

Therefore $I=\sum_n I_n$ and we only need to estimate the asymptotic behavior of $I_n$.

In fact, it could be estimate roughly, which is sufficient to determine the convergence of $I$:

$$\frac{(n\pi)^\beta}{1+((n+1)\pi)^\alpha\sin x}\le\frac{(n\pi+x)^\beta}{1+(n\pi+x)^\alpha\sin x}\le\frac{((n+1)\pi)^\beta}{1+(n\pi)^\alpha\sin x}\qquad 0\le x\le\pi$$

Both the leftest side and the rightest side could be integrated over the closed interval $[0,\pi]$ elementarily and they are asymptotically equivalent (approximately $Cn^{-1}\log n$ where $C$ is a constant).

I want to see closer to the preceding integral. Can we obtain the asymptotic expansion of $I_n$? Out of simplicity, take $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=0$, and with a slight modification, we'll deal with the simpler version (1).

I have tried Laplace's method but failed after some efforts. It seems that Laplace method could estimate $\int_0^{\pi/n}$ well, but $\int_{\pi/n}^{\pi/2}$ is not a negligible tail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We write the integrand as

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x + x\sin x} &= \frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{x\sin x}{1+n\pi\sin x}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x} \left[1 + O\left(\frac{x\sin x}{1+n\pi\sin x}\right)\right],
\end{align}
$$

where the $O(\cdots)$ holds uniformly for $n\geq 1$ and $x \in [0,\pi/2]$, so that

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x + x\sin x} \\
&\qquad= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x} + O\left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sin x}{(1+n\pi\sin x)^2}\,dx\right).
\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

We can estimate the integral in the $O(\cdots)$ by observing that

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sin x}{(1+n\pi\sin x)^2}\,dx &= \frac{1}{n^2 \pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sin x}{\left(\frac{1}{n\pi}+\sin x\right)^2}\,dx \\
&\sim \frac{1}{n^2 \pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x}\,dx
\end{align}
$$

by the dominated convergence theorem.

In light of this, $(1)$ becomes

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x + x\sin x} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
\tag{2}
$$

Now courtesy of Mathematica we have

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x} = \frac{\log\left(n\pi+\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}},
$$

which allows us to conclude from $(2)$ that

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x + x\sin x} = \frac{\log\left(n\pi+\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
> \tag{3}
> $$

Here's a plot showing the numerical value of the integral in blue and the asymptotic in purple for $1 \leq n \leq 10$.

[image]

As discussed in the comments, we can estimate the error term precisely by noting that the integrand of the error is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x+x\sin x} - \frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x} &= \frac{1+n\pi\sin x - 1 - n\pi\sin x - x\sin x}{(1+n\pi\sin x+x\sin x)(1+n\pi\sin x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2} \cdot \frac{-x\sin x}{\left(\sin x + \frac{1+x\sin x}{n\pi}\right)\left(\sin x + \frac{1}{n\pi}\right)},
\end{align}
$$

so that, by the dominated convergence theorem, the error is asymptotic to

$$
- \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x}\,dx = - \frac{2G}{n^2\pi^2},
$$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).  Thus

> $$
> \begin{align}
> &\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n\pi\sin x + x\sin x} \\
> &\qquad = \frac{\log\left(n\pi+\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}} - \frac{2G}{n^2\pi^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
> \tag{4}
> \end{align}
> $$

Here's a plot of the numerical integral in blue and this new asymptotic in purple.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly nice approach.  I'm interested to know if there is a more "mechanical" way to get the asymptotic.

Comment: I wonder whether we could look into $O(1/n)$. The $\sin$ function is very nasty. The major distribution of the integrand is near $0$, but we couldn't decompose the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ easily to obtain the result.

Comment: @FrankScience, it turns out that second integral wasn't so bad after all.  I was able to get rid of that terrible relative error and replace it by a much better absolute error.

Comment: Well, I'll compute it soon. Incidentally, does some method called *saddle point method* work for this integral? I have no idea about complex analysis and Cauchy integral theorem. It is said that such a method is very powerful in de Bruijn's *Asymptotic methods in analysis*.

Comment: The remainder is $\displaystyle\frac1{n^2\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin xdx}{\sin x+1/n\pi}{\sin x+(1+x\sin x)/n\pi}\asymp\frac1{n^2\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{xdx}{\sin x}$, where the absolute error is $\displaystyle-\frac1{n^3\pi^3}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(2\sin x+x\sin^2x+(1+x\sin x)/n\pi)xdx}{(\sin x+1/n\pi)(\sin x+(1+x\sin x)/n\pi)\sin x}$, which is not easy to determine the major part (it seems that Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem doesn't work well).

Comment: Typo, the remainder is $\displaystyle\frac1{n^2\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin xdx}{(\sin x+1/n\pi)(\sin x+(1+x\sin x)/n\pi)}$.

Comment: @FrankScience, For the integrand of the error I get

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x+x\sin x} - \frac{1}{1+n\pi\sin x} &= \frac{1+n\pi\sin x - 1 - n\pi\sin x - x\sin x}{(1+n\pi\sin x+x\sin x)(1+n\pi\sin x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2} \cdot \frac{-x\sin x}{\left(\sin x + \frac{1+x\sin x}{n\pi}\right)\left(\sin x + \frac{1}{n\pi}\right)},
\end{align}
$$

so the error is indeed asymptotic to

$$
- \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x}\,dx.
$$

We might be able to get another term by expanding the above integrand in series.  I'll check it out.

Comment: I doubt that it could be expanded. I guess the term after $Cn^{-2}$ is $O(n^{-3}\log n)$, not $O(n^{-3})$.

Comment: @FrankScience, Good eye, I agree.  As for the saddle point method, the contour happens to already lie on a path of steepest descent from a saddle point, so this might be as easy as it gets.  (Aside: I love that little book by de Bruijn!)

Comment: Huh, since these days I read part of de Bruijn's, I picked some stuff out from my mathematical analysis textbook and tried to determine the asymptotic behavior. Unfortunately, I found the road is extremely distorted. This one is just one of these problems. I've posted a new question related to the proof of the infinite product of sine. I will be pleased if there's some *asymptotic analyst* (professor) around me.

Comment: @FrankScience you should keep an eye out for answers by [joriki](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki), [Ron Gordon](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon), and [Sasha](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11069/sasha), too.  I learn a lot from them.

Comment: Although it's not a complete answer, it's well-informed and informative.